# How does Rao's score test relate to Lagrange Multipliers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I realize this sounds like a dumb question, since the score test is also known as the LM test... However, as I'm reading about how the test statistics/variances are found, I'm very confused as to how the test actually incorporates Lagrange multipliers. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: As a side note, the full name of the test is the Rao efficient score test, and we should always give credit to Rao instead of renaming tests years after they were invented.  Rao developed this around 1947 and Buse had a nice discussion about this history in _The American Statistician_ in 1982.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the null $\theta=\theta_0$ and examine the constrained optimization problem of maximizing the log-likelihood subject to the constraint imposed by the null:
$$
\phi=\log L(\theta)-\lambda(\theta-\theta_0)
$$
The first order conditions are
$$
\frac{\partial\log L(\theta)}{\partial\theta}=\lambda
$$
and
$$
\theta=\theta_0
$$
Substituting yields
$$
\frac{\partial\log L(\theta_0)}{\partial\theta}=\lambda
$$
The l.h.s. of this expression is, of course, the score, whereas the r.h.s. is the Lagrange multiplier.

Either version of the test statistic would next normalize by some estimator of the variance of the score/$\lambda$ under the null so as to get a standard normal test statistic when the null is true.